# Custom Flags for CMake

Tags: cmake

Not sure the right way to ask this, but basically, I have a project that I need to build in two slightly different ways. I could have two CMake files and keep them in sync, but I'd prefer to just have one and control it via a command line flag.

Something like `cmake --configure . --flag` vs `cmake --configure .`.

And then in the CMakeFile:

```
ifdef(flag)
line_that_is_different
endif()
```

to toggle the line on/off.

Obviously this isn't valid CMake, but is there some way to do this in Cmake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line:

```
cmake -Dflag=true
cmake -Dflag=On
cmake -Dflag=1
```

and in your cmake script:

```
if(flag)
   message(STATUS "FLAG IS ON")
endif()
```

See the [cmake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake.1.html) and [cmake if command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/if.html?highlight=#command:if).